# Image with itok "cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

Tags: views

We are uploading images to our site (Drupal 9.2.6). In the source of the page, the images are added to with an ?itok=. The browser cannot view the image and when I put it directly into the address bar it states "cannot be displayed because it contains errors".

The image is correctly created and in the file directory. After removing the query param from the url, the image works fine.

Any thoughts on what might cause this?

Comment: Try using Bartik, the default theme.  This is not a solution, but just a way to check if it is your theme that is causing the problem or something else.